# Quit "tab" from ul with css

Tags: html, css

The list on html have by default a "tab" for each item that I want to erase.

HTML code:

```
<h2>list title</h2>
<ul>
    <li>item one</li>
    <li>item two</li>
    ...
    <li>item n</li>
</ul>
```

this is the css I have:

```
.notstyled{list-style-type:none;}
```

and looks like (the "|" will be like the edge of the screen):

```
|list title
|
|    item one
|    item two
|    ...
|    item n
|
```

what I'm looking for will be having the list items at the edge, like this:

```
|list title
|
|item one
|item two
|...
|item n
|
```

I know the example is very stupid..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Clear the padding of the `ul`

```
ul { padding: 0; }
```

Just in case, you dont like the outer spacing of the ul clear the margin or padding as well.

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```